# I don't know why these outputs come out, (java thread)

Tags: java, multithreading

output :

```
Thread1 Start !! 

Thread2 Start !! 

Thread2 End !! 100001

Thread1 End !! 100001
```

i think output is 
{1,10001} or {10000,10001} 
because of sync...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main2 {
    public static int shared = 0;
    public synchronized static void sharedIncrease(long amount) {
        while(amount-->0) shared++;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        StrangeThread t1 = new StrangeThread(100000);
        StrangeThread t2 = new StrangeThread(1);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class StrangeThread extends Thread {
    long amount;
    int thrdNum;
    static int cnt = 1;
    StrangeThread(long value) {
        amount = value;
        thrdNum = cnt++;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread"+thrdNum+" Start !! ");
        Main2.sharedIncrease(this.amount);
        System.out.println("Thread"+thrdNum+" End !! "+Main2.shared);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this trivial amount of code, the first Thread may finish before the second Thread even starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following sequence of operations

1. Thread 1 starts. Prints `Thread1 Start !!`
2. Thread 2 starts. Prints `Thread2 Start !!`
3. Thread 1 acquires the lock and executes the logic in `sharedIncrease` (Thread 2 is blocked). When the method returns, `shared` will be 100000.
4. Now, thread 2 acquires the lock and executes. At the end `shared` will be 100001.
5. Thread 2 prints `Thread2 End !!`
6. Thread 1 prints `Thread1 End !!`

At points `5` and `6`, value of `shared` is 100001. (You can reverse 5 and 6 too; the result would be the same).

The key is that thread 1 wasn't able to print before thread 2 increments as part of its execution. Thus, you see the same result for both.